# Using multiple rabbit listener annotations. Only one is registering. Other throws exception

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I created two queue configurations each having its own `@RabbitListener` annotated methods.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class TestQueue extends QueueConfiguration {

public String getQueueName() {
   return "testQueue";
}

public String getRoutingKey() {
   return "testKey";
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "testQueue")
public void receive(Message message) { ... }

}
```

Another queue configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class AnotherTestQueue extends QueueConfiguration {

public String getQueueName() {
   return "anotherTestQueue";
}

public String getRoutingKey() {
   return "anotherTestKey";
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "anotherTestQueue")
public void receive(Message message) { ... }

}
```

Here is the base queue configuration where I create queue, exchange and binding:

```
public abstract class QueueConfiguration {

@Bean
public Queue mainQueue() {
   return new Queue(getQueueName());
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange mainExchange() {
   return new DirectExchange("main.exchange");
}

@Bean
public Binding mainExchangeBinding() {
   return BindingBuilder.build(mainQueue()).to(mainExchange()).with(getRoutingKey());
}

// getQueueName() and getRoutingKey() are abstract methods

}
```

Now the common configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class CommonConfiguration {

@Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            WfmMessageListener listener) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setAdviceChain(listener);
        return factory;
    }

@Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

When I start the app, I get the following error:

> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testQueue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]

I tried with just **one** queue configuration, it works fine! 
When I have more than one rabbit listener, it is throwing this error. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public abstract class QueueConfiguration`

The `Queue` definition `@Bean`s have to have unique bean names (the bean name is the method name, by default); since your config classes both subclass `QueueConfiguration` you will end up with one `@Bean` called `mainQueue`. The first definition is overridden by the second.

You need to move that `@Bean` into the subclasses and give them unique bean names

```java
public abstract Queue mainQueue();
```

```java
@Override
@Bean("someBeanName")
public Queue mainQueue() {
   return new Queue(getQueueName());
}
```

```java
@Override
@Bean("someOtherBeanName")
public Queue mainQueue() {
   return new Queue(getQueueName());
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Gary for quick reply! Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you tell me an efficient way to do this? I want to avoid defining beans in each queue config class. I have more than 50 queues.

Comment: You should really ask a new question; they don't like extended commentary here. You can declare multiple queues/bindings with `@Bean`s of type `Declarables` containing a list of same. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#collection-declaration). If your listeners all have the same signature, you don't need one for each queue.